# HIVE Group By in Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, hive, hql

Two tables - 'salaries' and 'master1'

The salaries is by year, and I can group them to get the sums for each player using

```
SELECT playerID, sum(salary) as sal 
FROM salaries 
GROUP BY playerID ORDER BY sal DESC LIMIT 10;
```

This returns the playerID and sum of salary, but I need the names of the players from the 'master1' table under column 'nameFirst' and 'nameLast'.  They have the common column of 'playerID' in both 'master1' and 'salaries' but when I try to run

```
SELECT master1.nameFirst, master1.nameLast, sum(salary) as sal 
FROM salaries, master1 
GROUP BY salaries.playerID ORDER BY sal DESC LIMIT 10;
```

I get the error
Expression not in `GROUP BY` key 'nameFirst'

I have tried tinkering with it to continue getting errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Need to include `nameFirst` and `nameLast` in the `group by`:

```
SELECT 
master1.nameFirst, 
master1.nameLast, 
sum(salary) as sal 
FROM salaries JOIN master1 ON salaries.playID = master1.playerID
GROUP BY master1.nameFirst, master1.nameLast, salaries.playerID 
ORDER BY sal DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you would need to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax

```
SELECT  
        MAX(m.nameFirst) FirstName,
        MAX(m.nameLast) LastName,
        SUM(s.salary) Salary
FROM master1 m
INNER JOIN salaries s ON m.playerID = s.playerID 
GROUP BY m.playerID
```

Use, `master1` table to get the *FirstName*, *LastName* and do the `JOIN` with 
`salaries` table to get the total salary of each player.

For, your current query exception when you are using `GROUP BY` clause make ensure that the *columns/expressions* in `SELECT` statement needs to be aggregate.